# Load resource file dynamically based on button click ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC application which needs to be translated to French. I have never implemented localization using resource files before. Currently I have two resource files, one each for English and french. The user currently has the ability to choose the language in the home screen by either clicking the English/French button. How do I load the resource file dynamically at runtime based on the language selected by the user? I don't need to take in to account of the language setting of the browser, the resources should be loaded only based on the language selected in the app. Any ideas on how this could be achieved please? I had a quick look online for solutions and couldn't find anything that loads resource files based on language selection within the app and ignoring the browser preferences.

Answer (score 0):

**Eidt**

It is enough to name the resource file with the same name but with an extension which makes difference in the language, for example

[image]

here is support for three languages (English, which is the file which has no special extension, Arabic with `ar.resx` extension, and Turkish with `tr.resx` extension)

You may also to control the properties of the resource file to make the files which are dedicated to another language has `No Code Generated` property. You can change this property from the top when you open any resource file

**Short Answer** 
you have to change the `Culture` of the thread like this

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
```

**Long Answer**

you need some code which is executed each time a new HTTP request is initiated. I am using the following code in my projects

```
public class LocalizedControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
    public const string _DefaultLanguage = "en";
    public const string _DefaultLanguageKey = "lang";

    public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        string lang = GetCurrentLanguageOrDefaultFromRouteData(requestContext);

        if (lang != _DefaultLanguage)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(_DefaultLanguage);
            }
        }

        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(controllerType) as IController;
    }

    private string GetCurrentLanguageOrDefaultFromRouteData(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        // Get the {language} parameter from the RouteData
        RouteValueDictionary routeData = requestContext.RouteData.Values;

        if (!routeData.ContainsKey(_DefaultLanguageKey))
            routeData[_DefaultLanguageKey] = _DefaultLanguage;

        return routeData[_DefaultLanguageKey].ToString();
    }
}
```

and you have to consider changing the route to make it accepting the required language

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    constraints: new { lang = "en|fr" },     
    defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and last you need to register the `LocalizedContollerActivator` when the Web Application start

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new DefaultControllerFactory(new LocalizedControllerActivator()));
}
```

the url should be look like this

```
http://yourDomainOrLocalhost/en/controllerName/actionName
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. How do I load the resources based on the language selected though? Should the resource files be under a resources folder?

Comment: Thank you.  I tried the above and I get this error 'The IControllerFactory 'System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'StartUp'.

Comment: I am so sorry to ask a million questions. It's just that I have never used resource strings before and still not quite sure how they work. I am not even sure how to assign the resource key value in .cshtml file.